# ACF flyback leakage inductor current problem

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback, clamp

I try to use Basso's Free SIMPLIS document to run the active clamp flyback, and I try to use math to build the leakage indcuctor current waveform, but I got some problems.
please see the below phenomenon.

[image]

Please see the active clamp part (Yellow Line).

Based on my math analysis, model 1 and model 2 has the same equivlent circuit.
So I use Mathcad to draw the leakage indcuctor current waveform, and the model 1 is the same with my Mathcad, but model 2 is not the same, you can see the waveform in the SIMPLIS and Mathcad are not the same, I don't understand if the equivelent circuit are the same, why the model 2 waveform is not correct in my Mathcad, does anyone know where I do wrong in my analysis?

[image]
[image]
[image]

From [VT's paper](https://u.dianyuan.com/bbs/u/22/1097257636.pdf), T3~T4, also has the same leakage current waveform as mine.

[image]
[image]

08/22:

[image]

Comment: I think it is a matter of resonance period of the clamp capacitor and the leakage inductance. Try to reduce the clamp capacitor to 0.22 µF and beef up the leakage to 13 µH and you will see the current curve you have derived.

Comment: Hi @VerbalKint, 

Please see the figure after I update the value you told me. 
Although the curve has a little change, but still can't 100% match my equation.
Why change the value will change the waveform behavior?

Comment: Hi @VerbalKint, 

May I know the reason why need to adjust these values?
Is it not suitable for this design?